# UITapGestureRecogniser Issue

Tags: uitapgesturerecognizer

UITapGestureRecogniser should work only when the image is present in the imageview. in my case, TapGesture works even the image is not present in the image view.

my code is:

```
func tapGestureRecogniser() {
        if let _ = displayImageView.image {
            let tapGestureRecogniser = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AddDiaryTableViewController.displayImageViewTapped(_:)))
            displayImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            displayImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecogniser)
        }
    }

    func displayImageViewTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("hello")
    }
```

tapGestureRecogniser() is called in viewDidLoad()

Comment: Please paste your code as text in your question.

Comment: add your code as text, not image!

Comment: this is the complete code....... for Tapgesture

Answer (score 1):

Implement delegate of your `tapGestureRecogniser` and return no there, untill you load image properly in your image view.